# Jinja loops to create indexed output like a while loop does with i+1

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to create a jinja loop to generate vlan configs in sequence, I have it working but wondering if there is a cleaner way.  Eventually I will pass the M value in a hostvars file.

thanks

```
{% set i = 1 %}

{% set M = 12 %}

{% for i in range(1, M+1) %}

      vlan-id {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

```
 vlan-id 1
 vlan-id 2
 vlan-id 3
 vlan-id 4
 vlan-id 5
 vlan-id 6
 vlan-id 7
 vlan-id 8
 vlan-id 9
 vlan-id 10
 vlan-id 11
 vlan-id 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're initializing `i` and `M` in the template. Assuming that `M` is already defined, you can write:

```
{% for i in range(M) %}
vlan-id {{i+1}}
{% endfor %}
```

And that's all you need.